# Facebook comments plugin - catch "submit comment" event?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

Is it somehow possible to catch the event when the user submits a comment with the Facebook comments social plugin?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.8

Comment: Holy ****.. dude.. My assumption that it is not possible to catch this event caused the final problems of my app.. You just made me really, really happy. Thanks so much, it works!